# calling bash function with a string

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash function:

```
function some_function()
{
   $*
}
```

I call this function like this:

```
some_function "cal 2014"
```

Why do I get a "cal 2014": not found error?

But it works if I call:

```
some_function "cal"
```

Comment: Because the shell is trying to find a command named 'cal 2014'.  Perhaps you are expecting the shell to behave as if you typed `eval $*`.

Comment: What shell and what version is this? Did you use `$*` or did you use `"$*"`? That behavior sounds like `"$*"` not `$*` to me.

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine the various behaviors here for a minute.

```
$ # Helper function to show some useful details.
$ c ()
{
    printf 'argc: %s\n' "$#";
    printf 'argv: %s\n' "$@"
}
$ # The function in question.
$ t ()
{
    printf '$*\n';
    c $*;
    $*;
    printf '"$*"\n';
    c "$*";
    "$*";
    printf '$@\n';
    c $@;
    $@;
    printf '"$@"\n';
    c "$@";
    "$@"
}
```

If we call the function like this `t "echo foo"` we get

```
$*
argc: 2
argv: echo
argv: foo
foo
"$*"
argc: 1
argv: echo foo
-bash: echo foo: command not found
$@
argc: 2
argv: echo
argv: foo
foo
"$@"
argc: 1
argv: echo foo
-bash: echo foo: command not found
```

- The `$*` and `$@` versions expand to two arguments and work correctly.
- The `"$*"` and `"$@"` versions expand to a single argument and fail.

What if we call it like this `t echo foo`?

```
$*
argc: 2
argv: echo
argv: foo
foo
"$*"
argc: 1
argv: echo foo
-bash: echo foo: command not found
$@
argc: 2
argv: echo
argv: foo
foo
"$@"
argc: 2
argv: echo
argv: foo
foo
```

- This time the `$*`, `$@` and `"$@"` versions all expand to two arguments and work.
- Only the `"$*"` version expands to a single argument and fails.

Ok. That makes sense since `$*` expands the arguments as individual (unquoted) words; `"$*"` expands to a single (quoted) word; `$@` expands like `$*`; and `"$@"` expands to individual (quoted) words.

What about if we try this `t echo "foo bar"`?

```
$*
argc: 3
argv: echo
argv: foo
argv: bar
foo bar
"$*"
argc: 1
argv: echo foo bar
-bash: echo foo bar: command not found
$@
argc: 3
argv: echo
argv: foo
argv: bar
foo bar
"$@"
argc: 2
argv: echo
argv: foo bar
foo bar
```

Now things get interesting.

- `$*` expands to three arguments. (Ok. I did say "individual (unquoted) words)" before.)
- `"$*"` expands to one argument. (Right, "single (quoted) word".)
- `$@` expands to three arguments. (Right, same as `$*`.)
- But `"$@"` expands to *two* arguments and keeps our internal space correctly. (As I said "individual (quoted) words)".)

This is why, in general, you always quote variables and almost always want to use the `@` expansions over the `*` expansions. Because they handle spaces and metacharacters correctly.

Ultimately though we didn't reproduce your problem when using `$*` directly. Are you sure you didn't use `"$*"` instead?

Comment: There are a lot of semicolons in there that don't look like they're necessary.  Did Bash flatten your history and insert them?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The ones in the function definitions? Yeah, those came from `type <fun>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you quote `"cal 2014"` like that, you are making it into a single parameter.  You may want `some_function "cal" "2014"` and see if that works better for you.  That said, I was not able to reproduce the error you describe.